# Jenkins ssh: Recover deleted ssh known host or recreate it?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Recently I got an error doing ssh to another remote server from Jenkins pipeline. I forget to save all the log but here's a part of it

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! 
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
```

In the error log, there's a suggestion to run this command to fix it

`sudo ssh-keygen -f "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "<<remote ssh ip>>"`
so I ran it.

Previously some remote ssh command does run before it returns an error.
But now it seems can't connect to the remote at all, the remote ssh command fails from the beginning.

`Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts).`

from [How can I get rid of " WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-can-i-get-rid-of-warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed) I tried running `ssh-keygen -R <<remote ssh ip>>` but the error still appear.

How can I recover the deleted line? or recreate a new one?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand what the message means before you "get rid of it".

The message means the destination server has changed its identity or someone is hacking you man-in-the-middle like and the server you are trying to reach, is not the server you think it is.

So first of all you must make sure there is no man-in-the-middle hack going on.
Then, you go into the `known_hosts` file and delete just the line with the server you are about to connect to.

After saving, you get asked wether you want to trust the server or not just as a connection to a yet unknown host.

Comment: I remember recreating the server with the same IP, I downgrade the server to another Ubuntu version. could it be the case? And how can I get asked whether to trust the unknown host? When I use PuTTY I got that message every time I connect to new server, but I can't figure out how to do that with ssh inside the Linux.

Comment: @otong The message from connecting to a new server is completely different from the message connecting to a host that has been in the `known_hosts` file before. When you reinstall a host system, it is very possible that the public host key changes.